# Ways to change dropdown choices in django-filter

Tags: django, django-filter

I'm trying to change the dropdown values for the user field. I want to show the email addreses , instead of the nombre + apellido. Because in my models I have the str that returns nombre + apellido, those are the values displayed in the dropdown. How can I change those values without changing the str in the Tutor model? Tryed to do a CustomManager but didn't work.

**MODEL:**

```
class Tutor(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=True)
    apellido = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=True)
    biografia = models.TextField()
    curriculum = models.FileField(upload_to="curriculums/", blank=True, null=True)
    foto = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    carrera = models.ManyToManyField(Carrera, blank=True)
    linea_invest = models.ManyToManyField(Linea_Invest, blank=True)
    correo = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    numero_celular = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Tutores"
        verbose_name = "Tutor"

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.nombre, self.apellido)
```

**FILTER**

```
class TutorFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    nombre = CharFilter(field_name="nombre", label="Nombre",lookup_expr='icontains')
    apellido = CharFilter(field_name="apellido", label="Apellido",lookup_expr='icontains')
    carrera = ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(field_name= "carrera", queryset= Carrera.objects.all())
    user = ModelChoiceFilter(field_name = "user", label = "correo", queryset = Tutor.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Tutor
        fields = ("nombre", "apellido", "carrera","user")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your TutorFilter. Change

```
 user = ModelChoiceFilter(field_name = "user", label = "correo", queryset = user.objects.all())
```

Comment: But here it returns also users that are not tutors. It returns all the users that are registered. How can I get only the users that are registered as tutors?

Comment: Try to filter it ---Tutor.objects.filter(user=self.object)

Answer (score 0):

How I solved:

```
def get_tutores():
    tutores = []
    for tut in Tutor.objects.all():
        tutores.append((tut.user.id,tut.user.email,))
    return tutores


class TutorFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    nombre = CharFilter(field_name="nombre", label="Nombre",lookup_expr='icontains')
    apellido = CharFilter(field_name="apellido", label="Apellido",lookup_expr='icontains')
    carrera = ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(field_name= "carrera", queryset= Carrera.objects.all())
    user = ChoiceFilter( label = "correo", choices=get_tutores())
    
    class Meta:
        model = Tutor
        fields = ("nombre", "apellido", "carrera","user")
```

See how I didn't need to change the str method in the model Tutor to display in the dropdown the tutor's emails as choices, because instead of using ModelChoiceFilter I changed to ChoiceFilter . Didn't know that you can call a function in the choices argument in the ChoiceFilter.